# How to pull active user name from drupal 6

Tags: 6, users

Is it possible to pull the active user name or active ldap user from my drupal site, and store this in a separate DB, as i would like to use it because the login limits who can access the site, but I want to know who is submitting x,y,z data into my forms? so at the top of the form maybe a field that pulls their username?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drupal 6 supports multiple DBMS connections easily in `settings.php` (to the same type of DBMS, eg 2 Mysql DBs, not 1 MySQL and 1 SQLServer).

You can use a function like [hook_user](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!hooks!core.php/function/hook_user/6) to track who has logged in and feed that username into your 2nd database using the database api and for instance the `db_query` function. You also likely need [db_set_active](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database.inc/function/db_set_active/6).

**EDIT**

I'm not sure exactly what your trying todo. You can always use [php's ldap functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ldap.php) to talk to ldap and look for info on the "user" (if they're not logged in yet I have no clue what you'd grad from ldap ...). You could always use [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!hooks!core.php/function/hook_form_alter/6) to assign additional submit handlers on any default drupal form to perform custom tasks.

Having used [ldap_integration](http://drupal.org/project/ldap_integration) for D6. You should realllly think about moving the site to D7 as the new [ldap](http://drupal.org/project/ldap) module is pretty nice and lets you save off ldap queries as re-runnable things :).

Comment: I wish I could use drupal 7 however the place I'm doing my placement with has too many sites and other project getting developed on drupal 6. Your answer sounds about right, I will have to give it a go on Monday. Thanks